# How to parallize the execution by hostgroup in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am dynamically creating the hostgroup by site and it did well with below recipe.

```
- name: "generate batches from batch_processor"
  batch_processor:
    inventory: "{{ inventory_url }}"
    ignore_applist:  "{{ ignore_applist | default('None') }}"
    ignore_podlist:  "{{ ignore_podlist | default('None') }}"
  register: batch_output

  - name: "Creating batches by site"
  include: batch_formatter.yml hostkey="{{ 'batch_' + item.key }}" hostlist="{{ item.value | list | join(',') }}"
  with_dict: "{{ batch_output.result['assignments'] }}"
```

In my playbook, i have like this

```
- hosts: batch_*
  serial: 10
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - include: roles/deployment/tasks/dotask.yml
```

I initially had `strategy: free` but in some reason it didn't pickup parallel. Currently i am using all batch hosts 10 at time to deploy.

I am thinking of below items
batch_site1 - 10 in parallel
batch_site2 - 10 in parallel
batch_site3 - 10 in parallel

But in the playbook, i don't want to specify the hostgroup execution by site as they are dynamic. Sometime, we will have siteX and sometime it wont be there. Please suggest the best approach.

Comment: Where does the `batch_processor` module come from?

Comment: It is custom python library which does all works and create batch of hosts by argument combinations. i have group of hosts like  `'group':
{ 'batch_site1' : [ host10, host11, host12 ] },
{ 'batch_site2' : [ host20, host21, host22 ] },
{ 'batch_site3' : [ host30, host31, host32 ] },
{ 'batch_site4' : [ host40, host41, host42 ] }}`

Answer (score 0):

```
- hosts: batch_*
  gather_facts: False
  strategy: free
  tasks:
    - include: roles/deployment/tasks/dotask.yml
      when: "'batch_site1' not in group_names"
      async: 600
      poll: 0
      register: job1

    - name: Wait for asynchronous job to end
      async_status:
        jid: '{{ job1.ansible_job_id }}'
      register: job_result1
      until: job_result1.finished
      retries: 30

    - include: roles/deployment/tasks/dotask.yml
      when: "'batch_site2' not in group_names"
      register: job2
      async: 600
      poll: 0

    - name: Wait for asynchronous job to end
      async_status:
        jid: '{{ job2.ansible_job_id }}'
      register: job_result2
      until: job_result2.finished
      retries: 30

    - include: roles/deployment/tasks/dotask.yml
      when: "'batch_site3' not in group_names"
      register: job3
      async: 600
      poll: 0

    - name: Wait for asynchronous job to end
      async_status:
        jid: '{{ job3.ansible_job_id }}'
      register: job_result3
      until: job_result3.finished
      retries: 30
```

This config slightly working on my purpose, however i couldn't pull the async_status to show better results in screen.

```
{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'job1' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/../../../../play.yml': line 12, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Wait for asynchronous job to end\n      ^ here\n"}
```

not sure why ?